# How to call references to other tables in a model rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, reference

I have a model called `cause.rb` which has a scope called `pesquisa` that I want to query in the table causes, fields that are references to other tables. I want to call the table places which have a field called city from the model cause.

Causes table:

```
class CreateCauses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :causes do |t|
      t.string :title, null: false
      t.text :description, null: false
      t.boolean :anonymous, default: false
      t.integer :count_likes, default: 0
      t.integer :count_dislikes, default: 0
      t.integer :count_visits, default: 0
      t.references :user
      t.references :category

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :causes, :user_id
    add_index :causes, :category_id
  end
end

class AddPlaceIdToCauses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :causes, :place_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Places table:

```
class CreatePlaces < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :places do |t|
      t.string :description
      t.decimal :latitude
      t.decimal :longitude
      t.references :city

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :places, :city_id
  end
end
```

Here is the scope:

```
scope :pesquisa, ->(pesquisa) { where("cause.place.city like :p or category_id like :p ", p: "%#{pesquisa}%") }
default_scope :order => "id desc"
```

How do I resolve this problem? I try this above `cause.place.city` to call the city in the table places but nothing happens.

Comment: What exactly is pesquisa? either way you need to join those tables together try add `joins(:place => :city)` in front of the where clause. You still need to update your query though.

Comment: pesquisa is a text_field_tag

Comment: Then may be you can't really filter it by `category_id` can't you? Try  `joins(:category, :place => :city).where("cities.name LIKE :p OR categories.name LIKE :p ", p: "%#{pesquisa}%")` I'm assuming that the text fields in category and city are named as `name`.

Comment: Perfect my friend, worked wonderfully!